# AngularJS not working on Internet Explorer - SCRIPT5022: No module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

i can't run my Angular App on all Internet Explorer version.

Here my index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="eee" ng-strict-di>
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

        <title ng-bind="viewTitle ? viewTitle + ' - eCube' : 'eCube'">eCube</title>

        <!-- header:css -->
        <!-- endinject -->

        <!-- header:js -->
        <!-- endinject -->

    </head>

    <body class="application-loading" ng-controller="bodyCtrl" ng-swipe-right="swipeRight()" ng-swipe-left="swipeLeft()" ng-class="{'no-connection': $errorConnection}">

        <div class="page-hider"></div>

        <div class="error-connection-hider error-container">
            <h2>No connection available</h2>
            <h4>Reconnecting...</h4>
        </div>

        <!-- Page container -->
        <div class="main-wrapper onload-animation" >

            <ui-view class="main-content"></ui-view>

            <div ng-include="'footer/footer.html'" class="onload-animation"></div>
        </div>


        <!-- bower:css -->
        <!-- endinject -->

        <!-- bower:js -->
        <!-- endinject -->

        <!-- inject:css -->
        <!-- endinject -->

        <!-- inject:js -->
        <!-- endinject -->

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </body>
</html>
```

And here my bodyCtrl

```
    angular.module('eee').controller('bodyCtrl',['$scope','$rootScope',function($scope,$rootScope){

    $scope.sidebar = false;
    $scope.sidebarVisible = false;

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

        $scope.sidebar = toState.data && toState.data.sidebar;
        $scope.sidebarVisible = $scope.sidebar && $scope.sidebarVisible;

    });

    $scope.swipeRight = function(){
        //mostra sidebar
        $scope.sidebarVisible = true;
    };

    $scope.swipeLeft = function(){
        //mostra sidebar
        $scope.sidebarVisible = false;
    };

    $scope.toggleSidebar = function($event){
        $event.preventDefault();
        $scope.sidebarVisible = !$scope.sidebarVisible;
    };

    $rootScope.$on('onSocketConnected',function(){
        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.$errorConnection = false;
        });
    });

    $rootScope.$on('onSocketError',function(){
        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
           $scope.$errorConnection = true; 
        });
    });

    $rootScope.$on('onLogin',function(){
        //$rootScope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.$errorConnection = false;
        //});
    });
}]);
```

When i try to run it on internet explorer it return me this error:

> SCRIPT5022: No module: eee

In all other browser all works fine. 
So, where is my fault?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The JS sample you added is it inline or have separate JS file? Coz i dont see JS file reference added to your html page. Try var myApp = angular.module('eee', []);  myApp.controller('bodyCtrl', .... The empty array in angular.module('eee', []). This array is the list of modules eee depends on.

Comment: The references to the JS are injected in the <!-- inject:js --> <!-- endinject -->.